# How to get nid from URL alias in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have a URL alias `sitepath/john/video/nature-beauty` where `john = user`, `video = content type` and `nature-beauty = node`. I am trying to get `nid` of node `nature-beauty`. Node title is `"Nature beauty"` actually. I have set node title in URL alias.

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong in below code?

```
   $last_page_visited = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   $alias =$last_page_visited;
   $path = drupal_lookup_path("source", $alias);
   $node = menu_get_object("node", 1, $path);
   $nid=$node->nid;
   print $nid;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will return the full URL, but the function `drupal_lookup_path()` takes only the alias as argument, so parse you URL and pass only the alias, `john/video/nature-beauty` then it will work.

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$path = preg_replace('/\//','',parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH),1);
$org_path = drupal_lookup_path("source", $path);
$node = menu_get_object("node", 1, $org_path);
$nid=$node->nid;
print $nid;
```

Comment: Yes and tried too. But after parsing url its displaying text "array" as parsed url.

Comment: @D-pak how did you parse?, which function you used

Comment: Here it is $parsed=drupal_parse_url($last_page_visited);

Comment: `drupal_parse_url()` will return an array containing path,query etc. 
Try  `preg_replace('/\//','',parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],PHP_URL_PATH),1);`

Comment: @wolverine  Please update your answer(by including code) so that it would be more clear for future readers :)

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Done :)

Answer (score 0):

There are number for of ways to get nid but its depend how your page is build. If its a direct node page then you can get using `$_GET["q"]` or using `arg()` function. You can also use `menu_get_object()` function directly and get the `$nid=$node->nid;`.

- `$_GET["q"]` would return like `node/2345` 2345 is your node nid.
- `arg(1)` would return node nid.

Comment: After using $_GET["q"] its giving correct answer. But how to do it with last visited page url?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. Just use `drupal_get_path_alias` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` to get url alias.

If you want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` you need to parse the it like follows.

```
   $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $filter = preg_replace('/\//','',parse_url($path,PHP_URL_PATH),1);
   $path = drupal_lookup_path("source", $filter);
   $node = menu_get_object("node", 1, $path);
   $nid=$node->nid;
   print $nid;
```

Comment: I am trying to get nid from the previously uploaded node url. And that's why i have written  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Comment: @D-pak Sorry for late response, I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes I have written same code before and it works fine, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']); 
$path = explode('/', $path);
echo $nid = $path[1];
```

Or simply arg(1) will return the node id of the page
By using this, you can get the nid of any node. But it should be the detail page of any node

Comment: How to do it for last visited page url?

Comment: did you check my answer

Comment: Yes and tried too. But after parsing url its displaying text "array" as parsed url.

Comment: I have made some modification in the code, its working example

Answer (score 0):

```
global $base_url;
$referrer = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], drupal_strlen($base_url));
$referrer = drupal_get_normal_path($referrer);
$referrer = trim($referrer, '/');
if (arg(0, $referrer) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1, $referrer)) {
  $nid = arg(1, $referrer);
}
```

That's it. $base_url includes subdirectory, if your site is not in server root: http://example.com/drupalsite. drupal_get_normal_path transforms alias into drupal internal path, that is, article/marvelous into node/101. It is actually a  wrapper around drupal_lookup_path, so the use of the latter is discouraged. And then you get your nid.